# Splash screen working on emulator Android studio but not on my mobile

Tags: android, ionic-framework, emulation, splash-screen, capacitor

I'm using ionic, capacitor and android to test and make an application.

I've generate splash and icon image with the command:

```
ionic cordova resources android
```

I build the project `npm run build`

I launch the project on android studio `npx cap open android`

When i launch the application the splash screen displays well on the emulator of Android Studio. But when i launch on my phone the image selected for the splash is not the good it is using like a icon image for the splash screen.

I'm using the last version for all the lib (i've started a project and i'm new in this field)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The created Splash Images are stored in the android project: android/app/res/drawable/splash
Check the images in there. In my case, there were somehow images for dark-mode created, that just have the app icon on a black background.

As my emulator was in light mode it showed the correct image, but on my real device I use the dark mode and so it had used the wrong image.

I just deleted those dark-mode images, so it always takes the light-mode images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add splash-night to your resources folder, as per official assets documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/assets